# Is "get_template_part" hierarchy possible?

Tags: customization, themes, get-template-part

I'm build a custom Wordpress theme using get_template_part to call tiny bits of code. I have file called "masthead.php" that is called using this code:

```
 <?php get_template_part( 'masthead' ); ?>
```

This works as expected. However, I would like to create some kind of file hierarchy inside my theme's folder. For example, if there's a file called "custom-masthead.php" use that file first but if the file does not exists, then use "masthead.php".

Is this something that can be accomplished?

***EDIT***

Following @sabreuse's code I'm trying to make things a little bit more complicated. I would like to print the theme's folder name instead of the $name variable so the folder's name is my main variable before falling into the fallback. I tried this code:

```
     <?php 
     $theme_name = wp_get_theme();
     get_template_part( 'masthead', 'echo $theme_name->Template;' ); ?>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Maybe it's not possible?

***EDIT***

Got it working:

```
     <?php 
     $my_theme = wp_get_theme();
     get_template_part( 'masthead', $my_theme->Template ); ?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Johann

Comment: you can read this http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you describe is already built in to the get_template_part() function:

```
<?php get_template_part( $slug, $name ); ?>
```

Where "masthead" is the general template slug in your example, and "custom" is the more specialized version. You'll have to name your parts slug-name.php (so, masthead-custom.php, rather than custom-masthead.php).

Note that you can also use the value returned by a function for the $name argument -- I do this all the time for things like:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );
```

In all cases, if the specialized template part isn't found, masthead.php is used as a fallback.

Comment: Hi @sabreuse! Thanks for your quick reply. That's is totally correct. Is there a way to print the folders name instead of $name ? Please check my edited post for what I'm trying to accomplish.